# Effectively changing constness of member variable in subclass

Tags: c++

While developing a game I have designed a class that in normal operation has a const member variable like so:

```
class Foo {
    /* ... */
protected:
    const boost::unordered_map<short, short> m_map;
};
```

However, in the accompanying game editor I would like to reuse the Foo class, but provide a way to edit this const member as it is used in rendering the game (and I would like to reuse the renderer for the editor). As such, I was planning on subclassing the Foo class in order to provide methods for changing various properties as well as serializing the data for saving the editor data. I'm wondering if there's an elegant way to do this while keeping the member as const or if there is a better design?

The options I have come up with so far are:

- Remove the const keyword and simply provide no public interface for changing the variable
- Change the renderer to use an interface and implement it separately in both Foo and the editor version of Foo
- Reimplement the public interface of Foo to use a new, mutable map for the editor version of Foo
- Something else entirely?

At first hand the interface path seems like the cleanest from a language perspective, but leads to an interface (abstract base class) for each and every class involved which is a decent effort. Suggestions and ideas welcome. (Note: I had a hard time coming up with a descriptive title; suggestions welcome for that also.)

Comment: "*Remove the const keyword and simply provide no public interface for changing the variable*" What drawback do you perceive for this approach? If your class was designed with const-correctness in mind then your `const` member functions won't be able to alter `m_map` anyway.

Comment: While true, it still seems kind of smelly given that normally the map should never change, which means that I lose the compile-time checks for that. I don't think it would be an issue since non-editor uses of Foo should use const references only, but it still irks me. It may be the best solution still, but I'm interested in seeing if there are better alternatives.

Comment: It's the idiomatic solution, otherwise your class loses assignability. In any case, making your member functions properly const does 50% of the work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If making your variable non-`const` and `protected` feels too intrusive perhaps you can have a design where the variable is non-`const` and `private`, and provide `protected` member functions to manipulate it with whatever constraints you had in mind when you made the variable `const` in the first place.

Comment: This strikes me as a potentially viable idea. I'm interested in seeing what other people think about this. Any takers? +1 in any case.

Comment: Sounds like a clean and simple solution to me! +1 from me too.

Answer (score 1):

Are they two separate projects/targets? There are those who don't like to use the preprocessor so much, but if they're compiled separately then I'd just use a compiler flag to build it one way for the game and one way for the editor:

```
#ifdef __EDITOR__
     boost::unordered_map<short, short> m_map;
#else
     const boost::unordered_map<short, short> m_map;
#endif
```

If I remember correctly for GCC you'll want something like `-D __EDITOR__`, but all good IDEs will have a field in the project setup where you can specify compiler flags. It saves you a lot of refactoring or adding additional complications to your code base.

Comment: The current design I have is three projects -- game, editor and renderer/game library. The renderer/library is currently designed to be use-agnostic so it would introduce a kind-of bi-directional dependency, which also seems less than ideal.

Comment: That's fair enough, but if the default case is that it should be protected then this would work. Personally I'd just remove the const and ensure I don't modify it, it's all too easy to ruin productivity fretting over such things!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your problem is a quite far-fetched. There is no reason in two classes with the same functionality. Do not repeat yourself. I suggest to create a single class with mutable attribute, add getter and setter, and do not use setter without necessity.